# Puppeteer: How to handle multiple tabs?

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

Scenario: Web form for developer app registration with two part workflow.

Page 1: Fill out developer app details and click on button to create Application ID, which opens, in a new tab...

Page 2: The App ID page. I need to copy the App ID from this page, then close the tab and go back to Page 1 and fill in the App ID (saved from Page 2), then submit the form.

I understand basic usage - how to open Page 1 and click the button which opens Page 2 - but how do I get a handle on Page 2 when it opens in a new tab?

Example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app'});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // go to the new bot registration page
    await page.goto('https://register.example.com/new', {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});

    // fill in the form info
    const form = await page.$('new-app-form');

    await page.focus('#input-appName');
    await page.type('App name here');

    await page.focus('#input-appDescription');
    await page.type('short description of app here');

    await page.click('.get-appId'); //opens new tab with Page 2

    // handle Page 2
    // get appID from Page 2
    // close Page 2

    // go back to Page 1
    await page.focus('#input-appId');
    await page.type(appIdSavedFromPage2);

    // submit the form
    await form.evaluate(form => form.submit());

    browser.close();
})();
```

**Update 2017-10-25**

- The work for Browser.pages has been [completed](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/pull/554) and [merged](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/commit/32398d11bdc2cd01c9cfe3e706f629ef90179c91)
- Fixes [Emit new Page objects when new tabs created #386](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/386) and [Request: browser.currentPage() or similar way to access Pages #443](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/443).

Still looking for a good usage example.

Answer (score 26):

A new patch has been committed two days ago and now you can use `browser.pages()` to access all Pages in current browser. 
Works fine, tried myself yesterday :)

Edit:

An example how to get a JSON value of a new page opened as 'target: _blank' link.

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'load'});

// click on a 'target:_blank' link
await page.click(someATag);

// get all the currently open pages as an array
let pages = await browser.pages();

// get the last element of the array (third in my case) and do some 
// hucus-pocus to get it as JSON...
const aHandle = await pages[3].evaluateHandle(() => document.body);

const resultHandle = await pages[3].evaluateHandle(body => 
  body.innerHTML, aHandle);

// get the JSON value of the page.
let jsonValue = await resultHandle.jsonValue();

// ...do something with JSON
```

Answer (score 15):

This will work for you in the latest alpha branch:

```
const newPagePromise = new Promise(x => browser.once('targetcreated', target => x(target.page())));
await page.click('my-link');
// handle Page 2: you can access new page DOM through newPage object
const newPage = await newPagePromise;
await newPage.waitForSelector('#appid');
const appidHandle = await page.$('#appid');
const appID = await page.evaluate(element=> element.innerHTML, appidHandle );
newPage.close()
[...]
//back to page 1 interactions
```

Be sure to use the last puppeteer version (from Github master branch) by setting *package.json* dependency to

```
"dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "git://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer"
},
```

Source: JoelEinbinder @ https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/386#issuecomment-343059315

Answer (score 9):

According to the [Official Documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#browserpages):

> #### browser.pages()
>
> - returns: `<`[`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)`<`[`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)`<`[`Page`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-page)`>>>` Promise which resolves to an array of all open pages. Non visible pages, such as `"background_page"`, will not be listed here. You can find them using [`target.page()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#targetpage).
>
> An array of all pages inside the Browser. In case of multiple browser contexts, the method will return an array with all the pages in all browser contexts.

**Example Usage:**

```
let pages = await browser.pages();
await pages[0].evaluate(() => { /* ... */ });
await pages[1].evaluate(() => { /* ... */ });
await pages[2].evaluate(() => { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: how do you use target.page() , this is not explicit in documentation ?

Answer (score 4):

In theory, you could override the `window.open` function to always open "new tabs" on your current page and navigate via history.

Your workflow would then be:

1. Override the `window.open` function:

   ```
   await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
     window.open = (url) => {
       top.location = url
     }
   })
   ```
2. Go to your first page and perform some actions:

   ```
   await page.goto(PAGE1_URL)
   // ... do stuff on page 1
   ```
3. Navigate to your second page by clicking the button and perform some actions there:

   ```
   await page.click('#button_that_opens_page_2')
   await page.waitForNavigation()
   // ... do stuff on page 2, extract any info required on page 1
   // e.g. const handle = await page.evaluate(() => { ... })
   ```
4. Return to your first page:

   ```
   await page.goBack()
   // or: await page.goto(PAGE1_URL)
   // ... do stuff on page 1, injecting info saved from page 2
   ```

This approach, obviously, has its drawbacks, but I find it simplifies multi-tab navigation drastically, which is especially useful if you're running parallel jobs on multiple tabs already. Unfortunately, current API doesn't make it an easy task.

Answer (score 4):

You could remove the need to switch page in case it is caused by `target="_blank"` attribute - by setting `target="_self"`

Example:

```
element = page.$(selector)

await page.evaluateHandle((el) => {
        el.target = '_self';
 }, element)

element.click()
```

Answer (score 2):

If your click action is emitting a pageload, then any subsequent scripts being ran are effectively lost. To get around this you need to trigger the action (a click in this case) but *not* `await` for it. Instead, wait for the pageload:

```
page.click('.get-appId');
await page.waitForNavigation();
```

This will allow your script to effectively wait for the next pageload event before proceeding with further actions.

Comment: Did not work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently - Follow https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/386 to know when the ability is added to puppeteer (hopefully soon)

Answer (score 1):

[it looks like there's a simple 'page.popup' event](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=master&show=api-event-popup)

> Page corresponding to "popup" window
>     Emitted when the page opens a new tab or window.
>
> ```
> const [popup] = await Promise.all([
>   new Promise(resolve => page.once('popup', resolve)),
>   page.click('a[target=_blank]'),
> ]);
> const [popup] = await Promise.all([
>   new Promise(resolve => page.once('popup', resolve)),
>   page.evaluate(() => window.open('https://example.com')),
> ]);
> ```

[credit to this github issue for easier 'targetcreated'](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3718)

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple inheritance from browser.newPage() to open multiple tabs

Example

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto("https://www.google.com/");



const page2 = await browser.newPage();
await page2.goto("https://www.youtube.com/");
```