# Using Puppeteer to get a handle to the new page after "_blank" click?

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

Looking at this simple code :

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page: Page = await browser.newPage();
await page.evaluate((a) =>
                        {

                             //This will  open a new page :  
                            ([...document.querySelectorAll("a")][0] as HTMLElement).click();
                        });
```

If the clicked `A`(anchor) element has `target="_blank"` , then the page would be opened as a new page.

It's not the original page object.

**Question:**

How can I get the new page object after a user has clicked on `<a target="_blank"` ?

Comment: Did you check [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806684/puppeteer-how-to-handle-multiple-tabs)?

Comment: @Andersson Thanks for response. Before I delete it as a dup , I didn't see in the answers there , How can I get a handle to the new page that was opened ( without scanning pages[])

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know another way to identify last opened tab except handling list of tabs...

Comment: You could probably save yourself a headache by using fetch() instead of clicking those if you're only after the page contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done like this:

```js
const [newTarget] = await Promise.all([
  // Await new target to be created with the proper opener
  new Promise(x => browser.on('targetcreated', target => {
    if (target.opener() !== page.target())
      return;
    browser.removeListener('targetcreated', arguments.callee);
    x();
  })),
  page.click('link'),
])
// Attach to the newly opened page.
const newPage = await newTarget.page();
```