# How to handle multiple windows in puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

> Like how we handle window handling in selenium.. Switching between parent window and child window. Can this be done in puppeteer ?

When I click on the link, it opens in a new tab, where I'll be doing some operations. Then I need to close that particular tab and return back to the previous tab and continue with that

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806684/puppeteer-how-to-handle-multiple-tabs

Comment: This was not the exact solution. When I click on the link, it opens in a new tab, where I'll be doing some operations. Then I need to close that particular tab and return back to the previous tab and continue with that

Comment: You can solve that based on many answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806684/puppeteer-how-to-handle-multiple-tabs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Puppeteer: How to handle multiple tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806684/puppeteer-how-to-handle-multiple-tabs)