# Managing the browser tab using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, automation, puppeteer, stack-overflow

I am using Puppeteer to automate web scraping tasks, and I am facing an issue with handling multiple tabs in the browser. I want to switch between tabs and retrieve data from each tab, but I'm encountering difficulties.

Here's what I have tried so far:

1. Launched a new browser instance using `puppeteer.launch()`.
2. Opened a new tab using `browser.newPage()`.
3. Navigated to a specific URL in the new tab using `page.goto()`.
4. Waited for the page to load using `page.waitForSelector()`.
5. Executed some code to extract data from the page using `page.evaluate()`.

However, I need to switch back to the original tab and repeat the process for other URLs.

Can anyone guide me on how to properly handle multiple tabs in Puppeteer and switch between them to retrieve data from each tab? Or switch back to main tab so that I can continue the loop ?Is there a way to identify and switch to a specific tab by its URL or title?

I tried using `page.bringToFront()` and `page.goBack()` methods, but they didn't work as expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Puppeteer: How to handle multiple tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806684/puppeteer-how-to-handle-multiple-tabs)